# Is there a way to make a flutter widget to disobey scaffold padding?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

My app screen has a lot of containers and according to the UX design, they're all supposed to be padded within the scaffold. Now there's one container that has the task of displaying error messages. I want just this container to occupy full width ie. not be padded.

Comment: please post your code

Comment: @JohnySaini just asking a theoretical question. Is it possible to make widget disobey padding or margins?

Comment: I am not getting your question.if you don't want to use padding or margin you can remove it or You can replace you scaffold widget with a container according to your requirement.

Comment: Scaffold does not any initial padding use media query to get device width and use it

Comment: @JohnySaini my app screen has a lot of containers and according to the UX design, they're all supposed to be padded within the scaffold. Now there's one container that has the task of displaying error messages. I want just this container to occupy full width ie. not be padded.

Comment: did you try with width: double.infinity. or  double.maxFinite ,MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the widget Stack as the root widget and put your scaffold inside. The container bellow will be displayed over the scaffold if it exists.

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Scaffold(
          body:...
    ),  
    Container(
      constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.red
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: Right on! Thank you so much for this!